# new servlet helloWorld

Tags: java, servlets

I am new in using servlet. I want to run a simple helloWorld servlet code but when run it ,I get this 404 error: The requested resource () is not available.

my project name is "ServletPractice".

my java class is:

```
package one;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

private String message;

public void init(){
    message = "hello world";
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException , ServletException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
}

public void destroy()
  {
      // do nothing.
  }

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

and my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>ServletPractice</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>
This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
the rendered HTML output.
If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
that submits the corresponding form.
If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
will be added as url parameters.
Default is 'true'</description>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>
If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
influence the HTML code.
Default is 'true'</description>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<description>
If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
Default is 'false'
</description>
<param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletPractice</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>ServletPractice</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletPractice</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/ServletPractice</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

error:

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type: Status report

message:

description: The requested resource () is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.16
```

and my address in addressbar is: 
    localhost:9090/ServletPractice/WEB-INF/web.xml

please help me. thankes

Comment: how are you trying to access this servlet?

Comment: the servlet class is wrong you need to refer it to HelloWorld class

Comment: @hossein Side note: you don't need `main` method in servlet.

Answer (score 2):

You are not mapping your servlet in `web.xml` crrectly. You are providing project name instead of Servlet name, Try this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>one.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Make sure you have restarted your server after making changes in `web.xml`

Comment: my friend it resolved. thanks for your helps . but I have a question:

after change web.xml code , at first run , my project address in browser addressbar was: 
localhost:9090/ServletPractice/WEB-INF/web.xml

but now it is right. what is reason??

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Servlet` declaration in `web.xml` file, like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>one.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then add a mapping to this `Servlet`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern> // or the pattern you want
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: my friends it resolved. thanks for your helps . but I have a question:

after change web.xml code , at first run , my project address in browser addressbar was: 
localhost:9090/ServletPractice/WEB-INF/web.xml

but now it is right. what is reason??

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your question?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add servlet declaration and url mapping for your servlet in web.xml file. 
    
    yourservletname
    classnamewithpackage

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>yourservletname</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/yourservletname</url-pattern>
```

Comment: in my project what is servlet name??